# Junit Testing a method that call rest api

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Here is the situation, I have a rest-client application that do all the rest calls. Eg. I can call the api class at other application and use it.

```
API api = new API();
api.setPath(....)
api.idget(...) something
```

So right now, I need to write Junit Test for my current method that call the api and get the id from the api.idget(String num) and use the id to do something else.

How should I test this method?

I have tried to use Mockito mock to mock the API

```
@Mock
API api;

Mockito.when(api.idget(.....).thenReturn(something)
```

I am so confused how I should test this method. By using mock method, I get the error on when() requires an argument that has to be a method call on mock.
I am sorry I cannot provide actual code. Anything would help.

Comment: Please give a [mcve], rather than a vague description. You could also look into using Wiremock to test the actual request.

Comment: Without code this is just a guess, but you could try this: `when(api.idget(any(String.class))).thenReturn(something);`

Answer (score -1):

you are correct. You need to use Mockito.when()

you need to call the correct method on Mockito.when

if you can provide the whole example, we can tell you what to do, right now, the only guess is, you are calling your method without arguments

```
Mockito.when(api.idget("5")).thenReturn(something)
```

please note the closing bracket ')' after the idget call - you are missing it in your example